# Javascript for loop console print in one line

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, printing, console

I'm trying to get the output from my for loop to print in a single line in the console.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 11; i += 1) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Right now it's

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

How can I get the output all in one line (like this
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`)?

Comment: just assign to a variable and logout your var ! instead of `console.log(i);` just do `myvar = myvar + '' + i;` and athe end of your loop `console.log(myvar);`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Build a string then log it after the loop.

```js
var s = "";
for(var i = 1; i < 11; i += 1) {
  s += i + " ";
}
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 10):

In Node.js you can also use the command:

`process.stdout.write()`

This will allow you to avoid adding filler variables to your scope and just print every item from the for loop.

Comment: I can think of two main circumstances when this may be helpful: 1) when an error may be thrown by code in the middle of the line, and you still want to assure there will be a partial output; and 2) when lots of computational resources are needed to calculate a result, and you want to ensure some feedback is given to the user from time to time, without causing the console to print a new line.

Answer (score 5):

No problem, just concatenate them together to one line:

```js
var result  = '';
for(var i = 1; i < 11; i += 1) {
  result = result + i;
}
console.log(result)
```

or better,

```js
console.log(Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(function(el, index){
   return index;
}).join(' '));
```

Keep going and learn the things! 
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There can be an alternative way to print counters in single row, console.log() put trailing newline without specifying and we cannot omit that.

```js
let str = '',i=1;
while(i<=10){
    str += i+'';
    i += 1;
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// 1 to n
const n = 10;

// create new array with numbers 0 to n
// remove skip first element (0) using splice
// join all the numbers (separated by space)
const stringOfNumbers = [...Array(n+1).keys()].splice(1).join(' ');

// output the result
console.log(stringOfNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let n=0;

for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
      n += i + “ “;
      console.log(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to print in a single row you can use repeat in Javascript-

```
for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    console.log('*'.repeat(j))    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `process.stdout.write()` method to print to the console without trailing newline. It only takes strings as arguments, but in this case `i + " "` is a string so it works:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i += 1) {
  process.stdout.write(i + " ");
}
```

**Note:** It will work only with Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `console.log()` into `process.stdout.write()`.
nb : if you are using `Nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may also try this like

**Program**

```
let s = '';
for(let i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
  s += `${i} `;
}
console.log(s);
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-conventional method; add the elements into an array and use the spread operator to spread your values in a single console log

```
const arr = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    arr.push(i)
}
console.log(...arr)
```