# How to print star pattern in javascript using console.log()?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am new to JavaScript. I want to print this star pattern using **console.log()** in JavaScript

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

I tried this code

```
for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  for(var j=1; j<=i; j++)
  {
   console.log('*');
  }
}
```

Each * is getting printed on a separate line.

Kindly help. Thanks :)

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089739/javascript-for-loop-console-print-in-one-line/33089779

Comment: In the future, before posting a question, you might want to do a search. For example, for this question, try googling for "console log same line" - you'll find many relevant answers on stack overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this code works

```
let star = "\n";

for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  for(var j=1; j<=i; j++)
  {
   star += '*'
  }
  star += "\n";
}

console.log(star);
```

It outputs

```
"
*
**
***
****
*****
"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  let startStr = '';
  for(var j=1; j<=i; j++)
  {
    startStr += '* '
  }
   console.log(startStr.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in regular JavaScript there is no way of printing to the console without a trailing newline, so instead, I'd suggest the following code

```
for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++){
    let finalString = ""
    for(var j=1; j<=i; j++){
      finalString += "* ";
    }
    console.log(finalString)
}
```

which saves the lines to a variable before printing them, removing the newline between them.
Another option might be

```
var finalString = ""
for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    finalString += "* "
    console.log(finalString)
}
```

which doesn't use nested loops but does a similar thing to the previous one, just more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is little bit tricky try out this -

**use string.repeat function**

```js
let star = "*";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        console.log(star.repeat(i));
    }
```